# Performance of mouseover on canvas vs mouse enter on html object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mousemove

I have a circle drawn on a canvas. At the moment i use canvas.mousemove to determine wether the mouse is inside the circle. Would it be better perfomancewise to place a round html object over the canvas and use the mouse enter and leave events of this html element? I think so because mouse move triggers more often.

Comment: Adding a layer of complexity with extra html elements will likely reduce performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of small amount of objects it does not matter - just take the approach that is more convenient for you.

For thousands of objects to check - pure canvas based approach shall be faster, more readable and occupy less memory.

In my personal taste layering anything above canvas to catch events or display anything is a misunderstanding.